# Java: get printer status (paper low/out)

Tags: java, printing

I have printed this way

```
FileWriter imp = new FileWriter("COM2");
while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
            imp.write(linea);
            imp.write(0x0A);
}
```

Well now Im using the port COM2, I have a printer that receive a hex code and its response will back in type byte, I dont know how to do it with java. Somebody has done it before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterStateReason](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/PrinterStateReason.html)

This class is a part of the [javax.print.*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html) packages.

Comment: Thanks for answer... Do you know if  is a way to this method getAttributes() , show the paper status ?
   PrintService printer = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        AttributeSet att = printer.getAttributes();
I only got 4 attributes.

Comment: @Sergio: No, it isn't.  You have to start with a DocPrintJob, define the document (Doc), and select the printer in order to access the PrinterStateReason.