# How to know the Network printer status using java?

Tags: java

To check the current status of the default printer we can  using a Java API. we need to over right attributeUpdate method.

```
@Override
    public void attributeUpdate(PrintServiceAttributeEvent psae)
    {

        Attribute[] att;
        att = psae.getAttributes().toArray();
        for (Attribute attribute : att)
            {
                System.out.println(attribute.toString());
            }
    }
```

But My Question here is will it send the request to physical printer and give us response or just check the driver installation form our local machine and give us the status?  If its from local machine, how can i send the request to physical printer and get the response?

Comment: Use the link of stack-overflow :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328519/java-get-printer-status-paper-low-out

Comment: well javax.print.* wont send a request to printer. it'll check the installation. i used this and check my printer status. weather i connect or not connect to the printer it'll give same answer. so it's only checking the printer drive installation.

Answer (score 0):

It will just query the local machine to determine attributes. If you want to actually send a packet, then you should use [snmp4j](http://ruchiram4.blogspot.com/2009/04/buil-your-own-snmp-monitoring-tool.html) or [LPR](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=775536)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i don't have any idea about snmp4j. I like to see some sample application how to use snmp4j in java.